# Windows phone 8.1 accessing buttons

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am trying to access buttons in my xaml page. i will make their foreground red. but i cannot access them.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
      Button button = this.FindName("Button_" + i);
      button.IsEnabled = false;
      button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);                    
}
```

The error is :

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)  C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Sayı TahminEt\Sayı TahminEt\Game.xaml.cs    61  33  Sayı
>   TahminEt

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the return value of `FindName`:

```
  Button button = (Button)this.FindName("Button_" + i);
```

Comment: if that solved your problem, please accept the answer by ticking the arrow